# How to make thumbnail images for custom Liferay Layouts?

Tags: layout, liferay

How to make thumbnail images for custom Liferay Layouts? If anyone has done it using any open-source software, please help!

Answer (score 3):

In Liferay 6.1 source folder `/liferay-portal-src-6.1.0-ce-ga1/portal-web/docroot/layouttpl` there is a zip file called `thumbnails.zip` which in turn contains `thumbnails.psd`, which contains thumbnail images for all the bundled layout templates. As for an open-source image image editing software, there is Gimp. Unfortunately, I didn't have much luck opening the mentioned file with it - the glossy overlay lost it alpha value and the large background rectangles seemingly lost their gradients and are all solidly colored. You could try Paint.net as well, which also stands in high regard among free image editing software.

The latest version of liferay docs containing any mention of layout templates thumbnails are for Liferay 6.0 series and you can find it [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template). There is also an empty png layout thumbnail template with proper background gradient, but you would have to make your own gloss over the little light rectangles as well as make the corners round...

All in all, you could also try to make the thumbnails from scratch, give them a more unique look. The image from Liferay docs should give you the idea of what it should like to still look nice next to bundled layouts' thumbnails. I'd just suggest to try and use vector image editing software. The bundled thumbnails all look simple enough to draw them with vectors, which would give you more flexibility and ability to change your mind anytime about details without having to draw everything all over again.

And that's for a 121x121 px image...

Comment: Fully agreed. I typically use Gimp and it takes longer to create this image than most of the actual LayoutTemplates. I typically start with the default png that's already declared and in the docroot folder. For customer-specific Layout templates that embed certain portlets or other static content, I typically add the logo to state what this layout template is thought to be for.
Still: Gimp is all you need. As you said: it's a small image, rarely seen by any eyes but the admin's

Comment: Olaf, is there any chance for a more gimp-friendly official layout template thumbnail template? I guess it's just a matter of exporting it to a different format and/or with gradient filters merged into layers for the graphics team.

Comment: Yes, there is a chance: Easiest way to get it into the product: Create one, file an issue on https://issues.liferay.com, attach it and set the issue to "contributed solution". Also, discuss it in the theming forum to make sure it gets attention and there's a good chance for it to be picked up.